# Implementing Permissions Database structure on a PHP site to restrict the Access in Multiple levels as

Tags: php, mysql, acl

I am working on a PHP site that shows the business of a Vehicle Showroom company in which we have 3 users as,

```
- Super Admin(Owner)
 - Super Manager
 - Manager

= Here Super Admin Have all Access by default
= Super Manager's access will be set by Super Admin
= Manager's Access can be ser by SUper Admin and Super Manager As well
```

The business include product in following manner,

Lets say for single District

```
- Districts - 1
      - Talukas - 8
           - Vehicle Family - 2 - 1Traditional - 2Non-traditional
               - Category - 9
                   - Prod Line - 24
                       - Vehicle Model - 55
```

And for this i have set viewing data Permissions for super manager upto the Vehicle Model level. Means i want to insert these kind of permissions to database tables.
  How can i design the databse table to save these permissions within the table?

The admin should be able to change the access level basec on the different district or talukas of vehicle family or prod line or vehicle model likewise.!

Comment: You need to decide at what level your permissions system kicks in: at page level (access denied if you don't hold a role), sub-page level (usually a menu item does not appear if you don't hold a role) and data (you can only see the data you are meant to). Your issue sounds like the third category, but you may need more than one. [I have an article](http://blog.jondh.me.uk/2010/06/handling-complex-permissions-with-sfguard/) on the topic - it's for an old framework, so don't worry about the code too much - but perhaps the description will be useful.

Comment: Hi halfer,
Your are right that my issue is somewhat related to third category and i viewed your link as well but didn't got the idea about my kind of database design.
If you could give me some other example showing the access data upto the Vehicle Model Level as well....!
Thanking You,

Comment: Are each of the things in the hierarchy a separate table (district, taluka, vehicle_family, category, prod_line, model)? If so, please edit into your question the `CREATE TABLE` syntax for all of them (or at least their column names/types).

Comment: Hi Halfer,
Yes, m having separate table for each one as...,

Comment: CREATE TABLE br_mgr_detail (
    mgr_id integer DEFAULT nextval('id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    fname character varying(20),
    mname character varying(20),
    lname character varying(20),
    date_of_birth date,
    branch_name character varying(30),
    location character varying(30),
    user_name character varying(20),
    password character varying(20),
    date_of_join date,
    created timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    last_modified timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    role_id integer
);

Comment: CREATE TABLE mgr_permission (
    mp_id integer NOT NULL,
    mp_mgr_id integer,
    district character varying(20),
    taluka character varying(20),
    enc_type character varying(25),
    family character varying(25),
    lob character varying(25),
    prod_line character varying(25),
    models character varying(25),
    created timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    last_modified timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);

Comment: CREATE TABLE location_district (
    ld_id integer NOT NULL,
    ld_name character varying(20),
    created timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now()
);


CREATE TABLE location_taluka (
    lt_id integer NOT NULL,
    lt_name character varying(20),
    created timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
    ld_id integer
);



CREATE TABLE v_family (
    vf_id integer NOT NULL,
    vf_type character varying(20) NOT NULL,
    et_id integer NOT NULL
);

Comment: CREATE TABLE v_lob (
    vl_id integer NOT NULL,
    vl_type character varying NOT NULL,
    vf_id integer NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE v_models (
    vm_id integer NOT NULL,
    vm_type character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    vp_id integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE v_prod_line (
    vp_id integer NOT NULL,
    vp_type character varying(20) NOT NULL,
    vl_id integer NOT NULL
);

Every Table is linked with another table by referencing its id

Comment: Please edit those things into the question, using the edit link - they can be formatted properly there. If you wouldn't mind then deleting them from the comments, it keeps things neat and tidy.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i design the databse table to save these permissions within the table?

You can do so by having one users table, one permissions table and one linking table linking  users with permissions.

```
+----------+     +----------+     +----------+
|   User   +---> |   Link   | <---+   Perm   |
+----------+     +----------+     +----------+
```

In your case you probably also want to organize users in groups. So another group table and one table linking groups with users. But as your three users represent all three groups 1:1, this is technically not necessary (but can be when the number of users grow and the 1:1 relationship breaks).

> The admin should be able to change the access level basec on the different district or talukas of vehicle family or prod line or vehicle model likewise.!

That you program into the meaning of the permission. Make permissions unique so that the business logic in your code can deal with that. You normally do not encode these rules into the database structure.

Comment: Hey hakre,
Thanx for your generous response,
Can you please elaborate the same with an example showing table for multiple level permission setting...?

Comment: There is only one level in permissions here: Having or not having the permission. And more is not needed. A higher level permission is just another permission next to a lower level permission. So a user with a higher level permission has two permissions then: the lower level permission and the higher level permission. The rest is in the business logic. And that's already written in the answer.

Comment: Hello hakre,
My question is that if Admin wants to show a manager with restricted district data or say he wants show only a particular Prod_line data or as well as particular Models data then how to store these kind of Permissions into an table as Admin can add or remove them at any time.
I am having a a page with html table showing the Customer data with his district, taluka, prod_line, model of vehicle he prefers and depend upon that data manager is been restricted the display of Customer.
NOW CAN YOU TELL ME HOW SHOULD I DO IT IN A EFFECTIVE WAY...?

Comment: You do this most effectively by encapsulating what varies and do the first implementation with as little code as necessary. Also by separating concerns. And by quick turnaround development cycles. There is no one size fits it all existing system that meets your criteria.